# Find top 1 record from join table for unique id by timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables, item, unique_item_code and unique_hist. item table has mapping relation with unique_item_code table and unique_item_code has mapping relation with unique_hist table. Every item has unique item code and that is available in unique_item_code table. unique_hist table contain the unique_code's other details and this table has multiple records for a unique code.

I have to get details from item table and unique_item_code table, but if there are more than 1 record available in unique_hist table for unique_code then take that latest one record which has last_updated_time less than flag_updated_time.

Table "**Item**":

| TID | SID | REVISION | IMPORT_FLAG | AMOUNT | ITEM | FLAG_UPDATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 657 | BX | 08-31-2023 10:20:10 |
| 65743 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 467 | BX | 08-30-2023 11:01:39 |
| 76543 | AB | 1 | 1 | 8753 | DU | 08-30-2023 09:01:39 |
| 86364 | F | 2 | 1 | 78 | TY | 09-03-2023 11:12:41 |
| 86364 | N | 0 | 1 | 5000 | RT | 08-22-2023 18:45:16 |

Table "**UNIQUE_ITEM_CODE**":

| TID | SID | REVISION | UNIQUE_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23456 | 0 | 0 | ASF456B |
| 65743 | 0 | 0 | FDGHJY6 |
| 76543 | AB | 1 | ET567BG |
| 86364 | F | 2 | MHFB78 |
| 86364 | N | 0 | 567HFV8 |

Table "**UNIQUE_HISTORY**":

| UNIQUE_CODE | PRIORITY | CLASS | TYPE | STATUS | LAST_UPDATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASF456B | HIGH | TTH | B | CLOSED | 08-31-2023 13:23:45 |
| FDGHJY6 | LOW | CAD | S | OPEN | 08-31-2023 09:32:25 |
| ET567BG | LOW | AUS | B | OPEN | 08-30-2023 10:00:11 |
| MHFB78 | LOW | AUS | B | TERMINATED | 09-03-2023 11:09:18 |
| 567HFV8 | LOW | EUR | S | OPEN | 08-22-2023 18:28:56 |
| ASF456B | LOW | CAD | S | CLOSED | 08-15-2023 23:32:42 |
| FDGHJY6 | HIGH | NXZ | B | HOLD | 08-30-2023 03:14:25 |
| FDGHJY6 | HIGH | NXZ | B | COMPLETE | 08-30-2023 03:16:15 |
| FDGHJY6 | LOW | TTH | S | CLOSED | 08-30-2023 14:20:02 |

"**Expected Output**":

| TID | SID | REVISION | IMPORT_FLAG | AMOUNT | ITEM | FLAG_UPDATE_TIME | UNIQUE_CODE | PRIORITY | CLASS | TYPE | LAST_UPDATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 657 | BX | 08-31-2023 10:20:10 | ASF456B | LOW | CAD | S | 08-15-2023 23:32:42 |
| 65743 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 467 | BX | 08-30-2023 11:01:39 | FDGHJY6 | HIGH | NXZ | B | 08-30-2023 03:16:15 |
| 76543 | AB | 1 | 1 | 8753 | DU | 08-30-2023 09:01:39 | ET567BG | LOW | AUS | B | 08-20-2023 07:00:11 |
| 86364 | F | 2 | 1 | 78 | TY | 09-03-2023 11:12:41 | MHFB78 | LOW | AUS | B | 09-03-2023 11:09:18 |
| 86364 | N | 0 | 1 | 5000 | RT | 08-22-2023 18:45:16 | 567HFV8 | LOW | EUR | S | 08-22-2023 18:28:56 |

I tried with this query:

```sql
select it.*, 
       hist.unique_code, 
       hist.priority, 
       hist.class, 
       hist.type, 
       hist.last_updated_time
from item it 
join unique_item_code uniq 
  on it.tid = uniq.tid 
 and it.sid = uniq.sid and it.revision = uniq.revision 
join unique_hist hist 
  on uniq.unique_code = hist.unique_code 
where it.flag_updated_time < hist.last_updated_time
```

And this one:

```sql
select it.*, 
       hist.unique_code, 
       hist.priority, 
       hist.class, 
       hist.type, 
       hist.last_updated_time 
from item it 
join unique_item_code uniq 
  on it.tid = uniq.tid 
 and it.sid = uniq.sid and it.revision = uniq.revision 
join (select top 1 
      from unique_hist hist 
      where it.flag_updated_time < last_updated_time 
        and uniq.unique_code = hist.unique_code)
```

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Comment: You need to 1) ask a question and 2) show your attempt even if the query isn't returning desired results. This is a Q&A forum, not a code-writing service.

Comment: @DaleK added queries which I tried

Comment: @DanGuzman added queries which I tried

Comment: Screenshots of spreadsheets should be for questions about spreadsheets please.

Comment: And for future reference, the editor has a code formatting option, please use it.

Comment: @DaleK added tables in proper way

Comment: @DanGuzman added tables in proper way

Comment: @Stu added tables in proper way

Comment: @Rahul, you said you need "which has last_updated_time less than flag_updated_time" but the query in your first attempt has the condition reversed (`where it.flag_updated_time < hist.last_updated_time`). You will get the expect results if you change it to `where hist.last_updated_time < it.flag_updated_time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unwrap your problem by filtering the records in your history table on your joined tables.

In order to filter your records safely, to get the first record for each partition ordered by date, you could use [`TOP(1) WITH TIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) when applied to a window function like `ROW_NUMBER`, that returns 1 for each partition, when two conditions on cascade are satisfied:

- "*flag_update_time*" is lower than "*last_update_time*"
- "*last_update_time*" is highest

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
       i.TID, 
       i.SID, 
       c.REVISION, 
       i.IMPORT_FLAG,
       i.AMOUNT,
       i.ITEM,
       i.FLAG_UPDATE_TIME,
       c.UNIQUE_CODE,
       hist.PRIORITY,
       hist.CLASS,
       hist.TYPE,
       hist.LAST_UPDATE_TIME
FROM       item i
INNER JOIN UNIQUE_ITEM_CODE c
        ON i.TID = c.TID
       AND i.SID = c.SID
INNER JOIN UNIQUE_HISTORY hist
        ON c.UNIQUE_CODE = hist.UNIQUE_CODE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hist.UNIQUE_CODE 
                           ORDER     BY CASE WHEN i.FLAG_UPDATE_TIME < hist.LAST_UPDATE_TIME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                                        hist.LAST_UPDATE_TIME DESC)
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BfyuuwKQ).

Comment: its not working for condition 'if there are more than 1 record available in unique_hist table for unique_code then take that latest one record which has last_updated_time less than flag_updated_time'. I have updated expected output and UNIQUE_HISTORY table data again.

Comment: i have added 'it.flag_updated_time < last_updated_time' in your code but still not getting as expected output

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the dates requirement. You can play with it in the linked fiddle. @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it in a couple of ways ...

Based on the expected output, you seem to want to show the record from unique_history with oldest last_update_time and older than or equal to the item.flag_update_time. In case you wanted the latest record from unique_history, then swap `MIN` for `MAX`

(1) Use a correlated subquery to get the oldest last_update_time from unique_history table that is older than or equal to  flag_update_time from the item table

```
select it.*, hist.unique_code, hist.priority, hist.class, hist.type, hist.last_update_time
from item it
    join unique_item_code uniq on it.tid = uniq.tid and it.sid = uniq.sid and it.revision = uniq.revision
    join unique_history hist on uniq.unique_code = hist.unique_code
where hist.last_update_time = ( select min(last_update_time)
from unique_history hist_min
where uniq.unique_code = hist_min.unique_code
    and it.flag_update_time >= hist_min.last_update_time )
```

(2)
Inside a CTE, use the MIN window function to get the oldest  last_update_time from unique_history table that is older than flag_update_time from the item table; and then only select only the rows matching the oldest last_update_time

```
;with
    cte
    as
    (
        select it.*, hist.unique_code, hist.priority, hist.class, hist.type, hist.last_update_time, min(hist.last_update_time) over (
    partition by hist.unique_code ) min_last_update_time
        from item it
            join unique_item_code uniq on it.tid = uniq.tid and it.sid = uniq.sid and it.revision = uniq.revision
            join unique_history hist on uniq.unique_code = hist.unique_code
                and it.flag_update_time >= hist.last_update_time
    )
select *
from cte
where last_update_time = min_last_update_time
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @Nandalal Seth  this solution is working for condition 'if there are more than 1 record available in unique_hist table for unique_code then take that latest one record which has last_updated_time less than flag_updated_time' but it does not working for unique_code 'ET567BG'

Comment: @Rahul, in your Expected Output you have given the LAST_UPDATE_TIME as 08-20-2023 07:00:11 which is older than FLAG_UPDATE_TIME of 08-30-2023 09:01:39, but in the table data you provided above LAST_UPDATE_TIME is 08-30-2023 10:00:11 which is newer than FLAG_UPDATE_TIME. So, if your table has data has per the expected results then the query should work fine. Or do you want to show history record even if the last_update_time is newer than flag_update_time ? I assumed in my query that history data would not be newer than item